# Как управлять url-ом пагинации Yii2 в зависимости от активного таба?

Tags: php, yii2, yii, pagination

Есть вызов пагинации

```
use yii\widgets\ListView;
    ListView::widget([
                'dataProvider'  => $model->depositsDataProvider,
                'itemView'      => '_update_deposits_item',
                'viewParams'    => ['siteClient' => $model],
                'pager' => [
                    'maxButtonCount' => 5,
                ],
                'layout' => count($model->depositsDataProvider->getModels()) > 5 ? $layout : "{items}\n{pager}",
            ]);
```

На странице есть несколько табов. При клике на необходимую страницу происходит перезагрузка , т.к. pjax не используется и активным становиться первый таб
ссылка имеет такой вид

```
<a href="/clients/update?site=abetter.bid&site_id=7&page=3&per-page=10" data-id="1"</a>
```

А нужно добавить имя текущего таба , к примеру  `deposits`

```
<a href="/clients/update?site=abetter.bid&site_id=7&page=3&per-page=10&a=deposits" data-id="1"</a>
```

Как это сделать или нужно переобределять методы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решилась переопределение метода renderPageButton класса LinkPager

```
protected function renderPageButton($label, $page, $class, $disabled, $active, $action)
    {
        $options = $this->linkContainerOptions;
        $linkWrapTag = ArrayHelper::remove($options, 'tag', 'li');
        Html::addCssClass($options, empty($class) ? $this->pageCssClass : $class);

        if ($active) {
            Html::addCssClass($options, $this->activePageCssClass);
        }
        if ($disabled) {
            Html::addCssClass($options, $this->disabledPageCssClass);
            $disabledItemOptions = $this->disabledListItemSubTagOptions;
            $tag = ArrayHelper::remove($disabledItemOptions, 'tag', 'span');

            return Html::tag($linkWrapTag, Html::tag($tag, $label, $disabledItemOptions), $options);
        }
        $linkOptions = $this->linkOptions;
        $linkOptions['data-page'] = $page;
        $actionUrl = '';
        if ($action !== ''){

            $actionUrl = '&a='.$action;
        }
        return Html::tag($linkWrapTag, Html::a($label, $this->pagination->createUrl($page).$actionUrl, $linkOptions), $options);
    }
```

Передаем активный таб `$action` и добавляем к `url`

```
return Html::tag($linkWrapTag, Html::a($label, $this->pagination->createUrl($page).$actionUrl, $linkOptions), $options);
```